# How to delete cookie value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a RubyOnRails Application. 
My application users will login using facebook account.
When user want to register, I was calling facebook login from my application then its working, But facebook current user cookie created this time.
If I call facebook login again then I am unable to get the login page, because facebook current user cookie is not allowing me to open login page.
If I remove facebook cookie manually, then I can get the login page.

Is it possible to remove facebook current user cookie in my browser?
or otherwise any other way is there for remove facebook cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only code running on Facebook's domain can delete cookies set by/for Facebook's domain, so no.